# p:selectManyCheckbox : getting the selected values into bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, web, primefaces

I want to assign a List of resources to a project and then i use selectManyCheckbox :[image]

the problem is although I select 2 resources. it return an empty list of resources(Utilisateur) but the project is successfully added :
[image]

and then this is my xhtml file:

```
          <p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{UtilisateurComponent.listUtilisateurs()}"  var="current" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                <p:column>
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="selectUser" value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.utilisateurs}"   >
                        <f:selectItem  var="utilisateurs" value="#{utilisateurs.iduser}" itemLabel=""/>
                        <f:converter converterId="entityConverter" />
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton image="save" ajax="false" style="margin-right:20px;" value="#{projetmsgs['navigation.save']}" action="#{ProjetComponent.saveProjetUtilisateurs1(ProjetComponent.projet,ProjetComponent.projet.utilisateurs)}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
</p:panel>
```

and this is the method save in the ProjetComponent:

```
private Projet projet;
    private Utilisateur utilisateurs;
    @Autowired
    private ProjetDAO projetDAO;
    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurDAO utilisateurDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ProjetService projetService;
    @Transactional
    public String saveProjetUtilisateurs1(Projet p, List<Utilisateur> utilisateur) {
        projet = projetService.saveProjetUtilisateurs(p, utilisateur);
        return "/jsf/projet/viewProjet.xhtml";
    }
```

and this the method save in the ProjetService class called by the component ProjetCompnent:

```
@Transactional
public Projet saveProjetUtilisateurs(Projet projet,List<Utilisateur> ut)
{

    projet.setAvancement(projet.getAvancement());
    projet.setConfidentialite(projet.getConfidentialite());
    projet.setDatedebut(projet.getDatedebut());
    projet.setDatefineffective(projet.getDatefineffective());
    projet.setDatefinprevu(projet.getDatefinprevu());
    projet.setDescription(projet.getDescription());
    projet.setDurreprojet(projet.getDurreprojet());
    projet.setNomprojet(projet.getNomprojet());
    projet.setObjectifprojet(projet.getObjectifprojet());
    projet.setStatut(projet.getStatut());
    projet.setUtilisateurs(ut);

    projet = projetDAO.store(projet);
    projetDAO.flush();
    return projet;
}
```

and this is the Projet Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Projet implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private Integer idprojet;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projets", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    java.util.List<com.gestion.projet.domain.Utilisateur> utilisateurs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Checkbox based multiple selection on Primeface Datatable, no need to use the explicit `h:selectManyCheckbox`.

You could do that by specifying `selectionMode="multiple"` attribute on first/last `p:column`.

See the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).